# tail latency and throughput

Tags: performance, latency, throughput

My understanding is that tail latency is a measure of the high percentiles (95th , 99th) of response times among a set of requests being launched into the system.

My question is that how the tail latency relates to throughput, otherwise said, say I targeted the system with a 100 req/seconds and then with a 1000 req/sec (with a uniform interarrival time), the 95th percentile at 100 req/sec varies largely in comparison to the  95th percentile at 1000 req/sec?

What tail latency value shall be reported? or otherwise tail latency is independent of throughput and shall be reported at each/several target throughput i.e. 100 and 1000 req/sec in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Tail latency is related to throughput. Your problem is closely related to the QoS situation (high-priority latency-critical applications vs. low-priority best-effort applications).

Besides, it only makes sense to test tail latency when the system is at full load.